# filtering rows based on equal column values in R

Tags: r, filter, rows, equals, subset

I'm new to R, but i'm trying to filter out rows of a dataset based on column values. The dataset `hg19` is in `BED` format with column headers, and I just want rows in which the values of columns 7 and 8 are equal, while still keeping the column header. This is what i've tried so far, but it I just get a bunch of rows with zero columns, and no column headers:

`non_coding= subset(hg19, hg19[8] == hg[7])`

Comment: Are you comparing the columns between two datasets (`hg19[8]` and `human_genes[7]`)?  Please provide a reproducible example.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: `non_coding = subset(hg19, hg19[,8] %in% human_genes[,7])` is what you need. But please read the link @akrun  posted on how to ask questions. The above code might result in duplicates. if you explain better what exactly you're trying to achive, we will be able to help you better

Comment: sorry that was a typo on my part, both columns are in the same data set. I'm trying to filter out non-coding genes, columns 7 and 8 in the dataset are for coding start and coding end. If the values in those two columns are the same, then the gene is non-coding and therefore I want to filter it out to use later.

Comment: lets say i have a data set like this     data
    v6 v7   v8  v9
    x  123  123  x
    x  123  456  x
    x  789  789  x
    x  123  789  x    
how do I filter so that only the rows in which the values for columns 7 and 8 are equal to each other? i've also tried this code   hg19 -> hg19[which(hg19$V7 == hg19$V8),]

Comment: You seem to not get that you have a misspelling of the second argument to `"=="`. You code will work that that typo is fixed. Voting to close.